# What theory of estimation does apply when estimation follows model selection?

Tags: time-series, estimation, multiple-regression, model-selection, least-squares

Almost two decades ago, Chatfield JRSS(1995)[vol.158,p.441] wrote that

```
Least-squares theory is known to not apply when the same data are used to formulate and
 fit a model so that estimation follows model selection. Substantial model selection
 biases can arise, particularly with subset selection methods in multiple regression
 and in time series analysis. Unfortunately ways of overcoming the problem are not so clear.
```

At least for the ordinary regression model with normally distributed errors, the above problem applies to the maximum likelihood estimator. At least for certain Gaussian AR processes, conditional likelihood methods lead to least-squares problems. So the statement is quite general. Has any real progress been done in this direction over the last 20 years? If yes, what theory does apply, particularly in multiple regression and in time series analysis, when estimation follows model selection?